# Restrict revisions to specific roles (in WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a platform that allows members to create textbooks, courses, classrooms, and "labs". Is there a way to allow only certain members to store more than, say, 3 revisions?

I thought that maybe I could do a check like:

`if(!has_cap('store_unlimited_revisions')) define('WP_REVISIONS', 3);`

Where everyone is limited to 3, except for those with `'store_unlimited_revisions'`. However, if there are 10 revisions already and you define 3, then only the latest 3 are saved and the rest removed when you create a new revision.

Would this work? If a person with the role (A) saves an instant before a person without the role (B), would person A lose their revisions because person B was the last person to define the revision limit?

If not, is there some other way to remove the oldest revision above 3 upon save?

Comment: You could try here too [Wordpress on Stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  I can dig up some SQL that'll purge old revisions that I've used in the past, perhaps this can be bent to fit what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hmm that could work. I'd rather not use SQL directly if I can help it though. I just discovered the `save_post` action and the `get_children` tag, which returns revisions. I think I could get something going with those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your first "would this work OK?" question - to be honest I'm not familiar with how that constant is used, nor specifically how/when revisions are purged based on that constant, so I can't answer that sorry.  Experiment with it yourself, I guess.

Re the "other way", here's how I'd do it.  Something like this will pull out all revisions for a given post ID:

```
SELECT 
 ID 

FROM 
 wp_posts 

WHERE 
 post_parent = {$id_of_post_being_saved}
 and
 post_type = 'revision'
 and 
 post_name like '{$id_of_post_being_saved}-revision%'

ORDER BY 
 id
```

(`post_name like '{$id_of_post_being_saved}-revision%'` included in the where clause to exclude eg autosaves).

Then could (back in PHP) establish if the count of revisions returned exceeds 3, and sort on `post_name` (eg "425-revision", "425-revision-2", "425-revision-3" etc for revisions of post id 425) or on `post_date` to get the "oldest" revision (whatever logic meets your needs, basically - either way I'd recommend some research/experimentation to confirm that logic will actually isolate the revision you're after, though, as I'm pulling this out of my head without having done this myself in practice!)

Now, this code I *have* used in practice, to delete ALL revisions on all posts (ie doing a clean-up of ALL old drafts prior to release to production on WP-based brochure-ware sites):

```
DELETE 
 a,b,c 

FROM 
 wp_posts a  

 LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b 
 ON (a.ID = b.object_id)  

 LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c 
 ON (a.ID = c.post_id)  

WHERE 
 a.post_type = 'revision'
```

But now that you have the post `ID` of the specific post's specific revision that you want to knock on the head (from the first query), add the following to the above where clause to do that:

```
 and a.id = {$post_id_to_delete}
```

NB This could all be implemented in one clever SQL statement, eg by using a self join between the first result set and grouped max of the first result set, and then deleting based on that... but personally I'd handle the "smarts" in PHP so that you can more easily adjust the logic (eg the older than 3 revisions rule) based on parameters available in WP/PHP etc.

Comment: Thanks brotha, I applied this and it worked. Frankly, I'm not a fan of accessing the database directly but in this case because I'm the only developer and I have full control I don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure mate, glad it helped.  I agree with you in principle, but at the end of the day if WP doesn't provide what you're after, then some kind of DB access is going to be necessary.  Ideally a plugin might already exist that does what you're after, but I reckon it's now up to you to create that ;-) (drop me a line if you do!).  I guess you can use the WP APIs to pass this SQL through to the DB, but I've not done much in that regard so not really sure what's available through eg wp_query, and if it'd be flexible enough for this. Take a look at WP's existing delete code to see what it does?